# Do scoping operators change what happens under the covers?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I have a situation here - basically:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
        virtual void foo()=0;
};

class B : A {
    public:
        void foo() { cout << "I hate this code." << endl; }
        void DoSomething() { /* Code */ }
};
```

A and B are in different files in my case, and much more complex needless to say - but here is my problem:

Somewhere within the class B in a function (like DoSomething()), I call foo.  Now, foo is a pure-virtual function from A properly defined in B, so it works fine - the compilation is fine too.

If I call it like:

```
B::foo()
```

it works great.

If I call it like:

```
foo()
```

It hangs the system at run time.  Why would scoping operators change the outcome when the function is not static or anything like that anyway?

PS: I wrote that code on the spot and didn't have a compiler for this question, so sorry for typos if there are any.

Comment: Whoa, it hangs the _entire system_?

Comment: The posted code cannot reproduce that problem. Post the minimal code which can actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your real code is going to be important. Perhaps you're calling `DoSomething` from a *more* derived class, where `foo` was overridden once again (and is hanging).

Comment: That is very strange.  First I'd make sure you're doing a clean build.  If the problem persists, you should step through the disassembly and see what the difference actually is.

Comment: So how did you instantiate the object on which you invoked foo?

Comment: It's an embedded system with multiple processes running, and yeah - it hangs everything.  This is a different issue all-together which has a good reason and that's fine, but it's not relevant, haha.  I just need to know what happens in C++ to make the two calls different under the covers.

Comment: There's no way I can post the real code, but there are just 2 classes, the base has a pv function like this, and the derived class implements the pv function.  Plenty of complex things are happening in the code, but the pv function is a simple print function.  @David Herrernan: The object this is called on (B) is dynamically allocated to answer

Comment: If you won't show code then how can you expect help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks correct. This strongly implies that the vptr or vtable have been corrupted by some out-of-bounds memory access, or that the `this` pointer is invalid.

The scoping operator changes the call by allowing it to bypass the virtual function lookup altogether.

Comment: Thanks, this is entirely possible given we have a large number of processes and lots of dynamic memory usage.  Maybe we over-ran an array and this is just where the effect is showing.